# Atomically deleting nftables chains fails in some cases

Tags: nftables

If I first run this script:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table inet filter {
   chain mychain1 {
      accept
   }

   chain mychain2 {
      ip daddr vmap { 1.1.1.1 : goto mychain1 }
   }
}
```

Then running this script fails:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush chain inet filter mychain1
flush chain inet filter mychain2

delete chain inet filter mychain1
delete chain inet filter mychain2
```

With the error:

```
Error: Could not process rule: Device or resource busy
delete chain inet filter mychain1
```

Is this expected?

I understand that I could just make two atomic steps: One to flush, and one to delete. But I would prefer the failure mode of one atomic step. Also, I would like to understand which limitations there are in nftables that prevents this from working.

My nftables version is 1.0.2 and my kernel version 5.15.74.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried with an nft version 1.0.6 and kernel 6.1.0-12 and it worked without issues.